# How to run a protractor browser.sleep for 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor

I have to run some tests agains a live site. 
I have to pretty much just make tasks to wait on a website to time out (15  minutes), then run another task, once that has passed.
the longest i got it to wait is 26.6 seconds (26600 ms) on firefox, and about 30 on chrome.

I get the following error :

Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

so basically i need adjust the specified timeout from jasmine to run this:

```
 browser.get('www.page.com');
 browser.sleep(900000);
 browser.doSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a *jasmine timeout* happening in your case. You need to tell Jasmine that it's okay it takes time. You can set the timeout globally in `jasmineNodeOpts` in your config:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 200000,
}
```

Or, you can also set it on a *spec level* ([example here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/9532779dd340b6db860b9aed3beca3a3673e51e4/spec/ng2/async_spec.js)).

Comment: thanks, actually as soon as i looked into the question i kind of got the answer. i used a variation of it. inside my before each i did jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000000;

Comment: @cXoltero yes, but don't forget to set it back to the initial timeout value in `afterEach` - as in the linked sample.

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeEach(function(){
        browser.waitForAngular();
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000000;
    });
```